# what is the difference between dplyr::copy_to and sparklyr::sdf_copy_to?

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I am using the library sparklyr to interact with 'spark'. There are two functions for put a data frame in a spark context. Such functions are '`dplyr::copy_to`' and '`sparklyr::sdf_copy_to`'. What is the difference and when is recommended to use one instead of the other?

Comment: The `sparklyr`one is implemented for spark data frames (following the RDD concept in a distributed environment), whereas `dplyr` works for R data frames, tibbles, etc...Is this what you are asking? I am not really sure

Comment: This answers the first part of my question The second part is: do they perform the same? In case "yes",  what situation is better to use one instead of the other one?

Comment: You can't use either one or the other. You cannot use `dplyr::copy_to` inside spark environment, **UNLESS** you collect your data frames from RDDs to R data frames. Vice versa for `sparklyr`

Comment: So if have two dataframes and I want to copy to the spark environment, there is absolutely no difference between them? I expected something as: is more efficiente the sparklyr version, or something in this way...

Comment: If your data frame is small enough to be handled locally (or not distributed) then `dplyr` will be more efficient. The thing about spark is that it is more efficient IF your data set is big enough to be analysed in a distributed env. So If you try any type of analysis on a small data set, it will be more efficient to do it locally using `dplyr` or any other R as per usual

Comment: so for big dataframes, is better the sparklyr version? Actually I came across of many problems trying to upload with dplyr version to spark, a dataframe with 2 millions of observations and just 3 columns. My solution was to split the dataframe in 4 pieces and upload separately, and later binding in one dataframe in spark. Do you think I could avoid this problem using the sparklyr version?

Comment: Of course. Just load the entire thing in spark and do the aggregations there. For me, I do all my aggregations in spark (but I use `pyspark` instead of `R`), and then I collect locally and continue in R (or python).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193406/discussion-between-sergio-marrero-marrero-and-sotos).

Answer (score 2):

They're the same. I would use `copy_to` rather than the specialist `sdf_copy_to` because it is more consistent with other data sources, but that's stylistic.

The function `copy_to` is a generic from `dplyr` and works with any data source which implements a `dplyr` backend.

You can use it with a spark connection because `sparklyr` implements  `copy_to.src_spark` and `copy_to.spark_connection`. They are not exposed to the user since you're supposed to use `copy_to` and let it dispatch to the correct method.

`copy_to.src_sparck` just calls `copy_to.spark_connection`:

```
#> sparklyr:::copy_to.src_spark
function (dest, df, name, overwrite, ...) 
{
    copy_to(spark_connection(dest), df, name, ...)
}
<bytecode: 0x5646b227a9d0>
<environment: namespace:sparklyr>
```

`copy_to.spark_connection` just calls `sdf_copy_to`:

```
#> sparklyr:::copy_to.spark_connection
function (dest, df, name = spark_table_name(substitute(df)), 
    overwrite = FALSE, memory = TRUE, repartition = 0L, ...) 
{
    sdf_copy_to(dest, df, name, memory, repartition, overwrite, 
        ...)
}
<bytecode: 0x5646b21ef120>
<environment: namespace:sparklyr>
```

`sdf_copy_to` follows the package-wide convention of prefixing with `"sdf_"` the functions related to Spark DataFrames. On the other hand, `copy_to` is from `dplyr` and `sparklyr` provides compatible methods for the convenience of `dplyr` users.